# Изменение даных в ресурсе drawable

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Есть кнопка:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_blue"
        android:text="@string/go_blue"
        style="@style/navigationButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

И ее drawable ресурс:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="false">
       <shape
           android:shape="rectangle"
           >
           <solid
               android:color="@color/colorAccent"
               />
           <size
               android:height="190dp"
               android:width="190dp"
               />
           <corners
               android:bottomLeftRadius="95dp"
               android:bottomRightRadius="95dp"
               android:topLeftRadius="95dp"
               android:topRightRadius="95dp"
               />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                />

       </shape>
   </item>

</selector>
```

**Мне нужно в java коде активити изменить цвет фона.**
**Возник такой вопрос** - Как можно программно сменить значение атрибута:

```
<solid  android:color="@color/colorAccent"  />
```

**Или как можно сменить фон фигуры ?**

Comment: Стандартный путь `button.setBackgroundColor(...)` не работает с `Drawable`?

Comment: @whalemare, нет, так не работает (

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Button go_blue= (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_blue);
```

...

```
StateListDrawable shapeDrawable = (StateListDrawable) go_blue.getBackground();
shapeDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Естественно где `Color.BLUE` int color - любой цвет

Comment: спасибо !!! Опять вы меня выручили )

Answer (score 2):

Создайте второй `xml` с необходимыми значениями и в нужный момент присваивайте:

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
 button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_button_drawable);
```